# Gradle task "compilePaidDebugJavaWithJavac" fails in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I've recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 Preview and I'm having this issue.
When I try and build my project from within Studio I will always get this error from Gradle

> Execution failed for task
>   ':Autosense:compilePaidDebugJavaWithJavac'.

If I go to the terminal and type

> ./gradlew compilePaidDebugJavaWithJavac

it completes successfully and then I'm able to deploy my apk from within studio.

The full error from Gradle in Studio says

> :Autosense:fabricGenerateResourcesPaidDebug
>
> :Autosense:processPaidDebugResources
>
> :Autosense:generatePaidDebugSources
>
> :Autosense:compilePaidDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> An exception has occurred in
>   the compiler (1.8.0_65). Please file a bug at the Java Bug Database
>   (http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) after checking the database for
>   duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your
>   report.  Thank you. com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure:
>   class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
>
> FAILED :Autosense:compileRetrolambdaPaidDebug UP-TO-DATE
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':Autosense:compilePaidDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

I've tried adding the --debug flag to Studio's Gradle flags.  This causes Studio to lockup on my machine.

I'm using Retrolambda with Java 1.8 and 1.7 on a Mac running OSX 10.11.1 with a 2.7 GHz Core i7 and 16GB RAM

Edit:
I've tried build tools 22.0.1, 23.0.1 and 23.0.2 as well as plugin version 1.5.0 and 2.0.0-alpha2

Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
//      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.11.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
```

App build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.15.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply from: '../quality/quality.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

def versionNumber = 97

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def gitBranch = 'git branch | grep \'*\''.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode = versionNumber
        applicationId 'com.autosenseapp'
        testApplicationId 'com.autosenseapp.tests'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled false
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_BRANCH", "\"${gitBranch}\""
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        community {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        disable "MockLocation"
        htmlReport true
        lintConfig file("${project.rootDir}/quality/lint.xml")
        htmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/reports/lint/lint-result.html")
        xmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/reports/lint/lint-result.xml")
    }
    productFlavors {
        paid {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SHOW_ADS", "false"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

retrolambda {
    jdk System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME")
    oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME")
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':imageResizer')
    compile project(':yWeatherGetter4a')
    compile project(':sliderPreference')
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':libraryFragmentTransactionExtended')
    compile project(':ambilWarna')
    compile project(':usbSerialForAndroid')
    compile project(':timePickerWithSeconds')
    compile files('libs/lastfm-java-0.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/updatechecker.jar')
    compile project(':spotifysdk-1.0.0-beta7')
    compile project(':viewserver')
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    communityCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    provided 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile files('libs/RootTools.jar')
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.findbugs:annotations:1.3.2'
    compile 'co.trikita:log:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.changeloglib:changelog:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3@aar'
// Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
compile 'com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:0.4.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

def outputFile = file("src/main/assets/apk_version.txt")
task generateVersionFile << {
    if (!outputFile.isFile()) {
        outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
        outputFile.createNewFile()
    }
    outputFile.write "$versionNumber"
}
```

Comment: I've edited to include build.gradle files

Comment: If you are going to do `compileSdkVersion 23` and `buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'`, make sure you specifiy `targetSdkVersion` with `23`.

Comment: I don't want to target 23 yet because of the permission changes.  I've been building agains 23 previously without error.

Comment: that is not recommended. Also, you are using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'` which is not a full release along with a `preview` ide. There could be a number of reasons why this is not working.

Comment: I know it's a preview ide.  I just tried bumping the targetSdkVersion to 23 and it indeed fixed Studios problem.  But now it has caused all the security exceptions I was wanting to avoid.
I guess my options are downgrade to 22 or fix the actual problem.
Thanks, at least I know what the issue is.

Comment: I was wrong.  It still isn't working.

Comment: Can you compile via command line? `gradlew assemblePaidDebug`?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine from the command line.

Comment: Then it must be the IDE.